# Sharepoint, Licences, Foundation, Enterprise, developer, etc providing dynamic content

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, licensing, enterprise, foundation

Yes I know this question shouldn't be on this site but I'm not getting anything from the Sharepoint site. Is there a way to do interesting stuff like allow users to update an access database where those users just have Sharepoint Foundation? It looks like to make a site interactive with a DB you need a combination of Enterprise/Access services/Developer but once you've created a site can users with just Foundation use it? I doubt it but I might as well ask...

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Mark

Comment: Since this doesn't seem to directly relate to programming, but rather administering server software, this question is probably more appropriate for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). You are more likely to find someone who can help with your answer there.

Comment: Cheers Eestrada...I'll consider this...

Comment: If you know that a question doesn't belong here, then don't ask it. It's obnoxious and makes more work for other people to clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right when you say, that you need an Enterprise Edition of SharePoint supporting Access Services for your desired scenario. And it is not possible to build it on an Enterprise environment and copy/move/restore it on a Foundation environment!

Comment: You are correct you can't put Enterprise in to Foundation, but they can get data from the AccessDBs without pulling it into SharePoint using BCS.  And in a lot of cases without writing code.

Comment: Thats right! Your way is a possible solution. I was focused on bringing an Access Database directly into SP through Access Services.

Comment: Thanks folks.  You've answered my question.  I need to look into BCS and take it from there....

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact you can do all of this using SharePoint Business Connectivity Services (BCS).  BCS allows users to make use of SharePoint to access external data.  You can use BCS to do all your basic CRUD operations to an external system.  Best part?  The features you are asking about are part of SharePoint Foundation.
What you need is External Content Types.  External content types define your connection and the objects you bring back from the external data.  You can then surface them within SharePoint using External Lists.  You can also update, insert, and delete data from these lists.

I have actually started writing a series on basic uses of BCS on my blog.  You can read what I have so far [here](http://prairiedeveloper.com/?p=234).  I hope to have the next post in the series out this week.

Hope this helps.

David

Comment: BCS seems an interesting angle.  I'll look into this but appreciate your response....